# CSS3 rotate3d pr rotateX get actual height of element

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms, perspective

I want to get actual height of element when rotated 3d on x axis. I'll try to explain with graphics below:

Element's normal height: 200px
[image]

Actual height is 118px when rotate 45 degree with 100px perpective:
[image]

Actual height is 138px when rotate 45 degree with 1000px perpective:
[image]

Normal formule for calculate this height value (without perpective):

`x = h * sin(angle)`

Height must 142px with this formule. But it's diffrent from this value. Probably perspective changes height. But I don't find any formule for calculate this height.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648018/calculate-absolute-dimensions-of-a-div-rotated-in-perspective-with-css3

Comment: It would be very nice if this height, the "rendered height", were accessible through the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I benefited from [efe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682805/efe)'s comment and calculated real view height of rotated element.

There is technical explanation about solution on [djjeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480483/djjeck)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8669211/673223).

You can view this question's answer with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TqJJL/3/

Calculate real height with this code:

```
// initial coordinates
var A = 0;
var B = width; // default size of element
// new coordinates
A = calc(A, angle*Math.PI/180, p);
B = calc(B, angle*Math.PI/180, p);
// translate back
A += width/2;
B += width/2;
if(B < A) { var tmp = A; A = B; B = tmp; } // swap

var realHeight = B-A;

function calc(oldx, angle, p) {
    var x = Math.cos(angle) * oldx;
    var z = Math.sin(angle) * oldx;

    return x * p / (p+z);
}
```