# CSS rotated/slanting table header border alignment

Tags: html, css

I need to make a slanting/rotated table headers, how do I make the *slanting* *inner-side* header border to align nicely with the vertical border of the table cell element?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column1</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column2</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column3</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column4</span></div></th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>RowDisplay1000</td>
        <td>Row12</td>
        <td>Row13</td>
        <td>Row14</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>RowDisplay2000</td>
        <td>Row22</td>
        <td>Row23</td>
        <td>Row24</td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
th.rotate {
  /* Something you can count on */
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(25px, 51px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}
th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 7px 10px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
}
table td
/*, #rotated th*/ 
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table tr:first-child th {
    border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Verdeairo/gwnx03vg/

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648018/calculate-absolute-dimensions-of-a-div-rotated-in-perspective-with-css3

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the headers a bit, like

```
th.rotate > div {
      transform: 
        /* Magic Numbers */
        translate(-18px, 51px)
        /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
        rotate(315deg);
      width: 30px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/gwnx03vg/2/

Here's what I did:

1. Removed the height of `th`

```
th.rotate {
    /* Something you can count on */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

2. Added the `transform-origin` property and changed the `translate` value

```
th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    translate(-7px, -2px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(315deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    width: 30px;
}
```